# How to alter a foreign key in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I created a table in PostgreSQL with a foreign key constraint.

I dropped the table to which the foreign key belongs. Now how to alter the table or how to defer the foreign key present in the table?

To clarify:

I have a table named `test`. It has a column called `subjectName`, which is a foreign key of `subject` Table. Now I dropped `subject` table. How to remove the FK constaint on table `test`

Comment: remove the constraint?

Comment: If you dropped the table, the foreign key is gone.

Comment: How about `ALTER TABLE foobar DROP CONSTRAINT barfoo;`? See [official docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-alter.html#DDL-ALTER-REMOVING-A-CONSTRAINT) for more info..

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I might be wrong but I guess he meant _`I dropped the table to which the foreign key refers to..`_

Comment: @iLuvLogix: then either dropping of the table did not work or Anu included the `cascade` option in which case the foreign key was dropped as well.

Comment: Can you clarify and add some details to your question Anu?

Comment: I have a table  named test. It has a column called subjectName, which is a foreign key of subject Table. Now I dropped Subject table. How to remove the FK constraint on table test

Comment: If you really dropped the subject table, then the foreign key was dropped as well

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following tables:

```
create table subject
(
  name varchar(10) primary key
);

create table test
(
  some_column integer,
  subject_name varchar(10) not null references subject
);
```

there are two scenarios what could have happened when you dropped the table `subject`:

1. you didn't actually drop it:

```
drop table subject;

ERROR: cannot drop table subject because other objects depend on it
  Detail: constraint test_subject_name_fkey on table test depends on table subject
  Hint: Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
```

2. you did drop it, then the foreign key is gone as well.

```
drop table subject cascade;
NOTICE:  drop cascades to constraint test_subject_name_fkey on table test
```

which tells you that the foreign key constraint was automatically dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your question in not exactly what you mean. Are you wanting to remove the which was a foreign key from the table. As amply indicated if you dropped the parent table then the FK is also dropped. However the **column itself is not dropped** from the child table. To remove that you need to alter the table.

```
alter table test drop column subject_name;
```

See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=91df2419e91b445997923553f3ef1c3e)